# How to load a page A in iframe of index page with javascript when page is called by browser URL?

Tags: javascript, iframe

How to load a page a in `iframe` of index page with `javascript` when page is called by browser URL?
I just want to load my contents in an iFrame in my index-page.
So when someone try to open this [site](http://sitex.com/registration.php).I want to load registration.php in the iFrame of my index.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the click event for links on your page, then grab the href value from the link clicked, and set the src attribute to that value. You can use the setAttribute and getAttribute DOM element methods to manipulate DOM attributes.